# i didn't understand the utility of file=sys.stderr in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started learning python and I'm currently learning about `sys`, `try` and `except`.

What I don't understand is the object `sys.stderr` and `file=sys.stderr`.

I want to know the difference between both of them, along with the utility of each one, and finally the reason why we must add `import sys` before using `sys`.

Why do I get, in the following code, the same result when I don't add `file=sys.stderr`?

```py
import sys
number = input(">")
try:
    number = int(number)
except :
    print(".....",file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: "why we must add `import sys` before using sys" - try running your code _without_ `import sys` and read the error message you'll get.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)

Comment: I recommend you take a course on Python otherwise you are going to continue learning in the wrong order.  Very inefficient.  You are ''learning' about exception handling, an advanced concept, and missed a critical first day lesson of how to import libraries.

Answer (score 4):

By default, both `stdout` and `stderr` are connected to the terminal. But you can redirect them separately.

It's common to redirect `stdout` to a file or pipe to capture the results of a program, while `stderr` is kept on the terminal.

Other times, the user isn't interested in seeing error messages, so they redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` while keeping normal output going to the terminal.

Printing your error messages to `sys.stderr` ensures that your script can be used in these ways, just like normal commands.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get the same result when adding or not adding `file=sys.stderr` gets obvious when you look at the help of print:

```
>>> help(print)
Help on built-in function print in module builtins:

print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
```

The default value of `file` is `sys.stdout`. Both `stdout` and `stderr` are just used to display text from your program in the terminal, by default. See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) for more details on standard streams. A quote from there:

> It is acceptable and normal to direct standard output and standard
>   error to the same destination, such as the text terminal.